# Getting only gray screen when launching citrix application

Tags: wpf, citrix

Recently we installed a .net WPF application on citrix. When I go and launch it from citrix using RES powerfuse, I only get a grey screen and no controls are rendered on the screen.

The application is open and the main window can be seen but everything is grey in it. The mouse pointer also disappears behind the application.

The funny part is when the people from the operations team launch the application, it works fine. but not for regular users. This makes me suspect it could be something to do with permissions, yet we have given the access to open the program to all users, thats why the icon appears in citrix in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What server are you running the app on? I recall we hit a WPF rendering bug on certain versions of Windows Server (+ XenApp) where the app would only render properly for administrators. This was a .NET bug - nothing to do with Citrix per-say. From what I remember the WPF rendering engine was trying to get access to some system resource that regular users could not access. I believe we only saw this on 2003 servers.

Just did some further digging, I think this is the issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955692

Comment: thanks I had found the answer thanks to related questions here. It is because of this issue. The directx cache file gets created in the System32 directory and normal users cant access it. After installing the hotfix, the directx file is always created in the UserProfile directory

Answer (score 0):

For quick n temporary resolution:
Check your local machine resolution and Citrix desktop/application resolution.

Equalise the both it will work.
Ex: **1024/762** is the right resolution. 
For test: Do maximise n minimize the screen you will see the change.